# is the concatenation of White noise process samples in a vector white also?

Tags: probability, random-variables, signal-processing

Given that $X_t \sim N\left( {0,{I_2}{\sigma ^2}} \right)$ is a bivariate white noise process, what are the characteristic of the new process ${Y_t} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{{X_t}}\\
 \vdots \\{{X_{t + n - 1}}}\end{array}} \right]$ , is it white also , what is its covariance matrix?

Comment: why ? , can you prove it ?

Comment: your answer is very vague , we are supposed to prove that the covariance matrix of $Y_t$ is not diagonal , hence they are correlated and can't be white noise

Comment: you are joking right , i said it is given that it is a white noise

Comment: i meant iid white noise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of intuition of why $Y_t$ is not a white process. If it were white it would mean that the two variables $Y_{t+\tau}$ and $Y_{t}$ are uncovariated for *any* $\tau\neq 0$. But for example

$$
Y_{t+1}=
\begin{bmatrix} X_{t+1} \\
\vdots\\
X_{t+n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is clearly correlated with $Y_t$ (a lot of the elements are actually the same). So clearly it is **not** white. Speaking of covariance matrix, do you refer to the $2\times n$ vectorized version?

Comment: what do you mean by $2 \times n$ vectorized version , i meant the covariance matrix of ${Y_t}$

Comment: as you wrote it, $Y_t$ is a $n\times 2$ matrix, right? Or is it a $2n\times 1$ vector?

Comment: no it is $2n \times 1$ since ${X_t} \in {R^2}$

Comment: Ok, just a difference of notation.

Comment: Then the covariance becomes pretty easy as usual as $\mathbb{E}[(Y_t-\mathbb{E}[Y_t])^T(Y_{t+\tau}-\mathbb{E}[Y_{t+\tau}])]$. Then you can write it as a block matrix, some of the blocks will be zero and others can be expressed in term of the covariance of the $X$ process. It will turn out it is not a diagonal matrix.

Comment: i thought the covariance matrix estimate is given by $E\left( {{Y_t}Y_t^T} \right)$, actually the correlation

Comment: Aside from that im calculating the sample correlation matrix $R = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{Y_i}Y_i^T}$ but it is not matching with theoretical one $R = E\left( {{Y_t}Y_t^T} \right)$

Comment: yep, it was a typo on my side (or depends if you use row or column vectors).
Sample correlation can be calculated when you have a sample of $n$ known instances, which cannot be used to prove the thing you want to prove.

Comment: theoretically the sample correlation of ${{Y_t}}$ indicates it is the identity, but from my simulations im getting a non identity matrix, thats why im confused

Comment: $Y_t$ is a vector-valued random process. The autocorrelation is defined as $\mathbb{E}[Y_{t+\tau}Y_t^T]$, not as the entry-wise correlation (correlation between the entries), as you are computing.